# HTML JavaScript, how would I be able to make this function work using JavaScript by giving each element a different Id

Tags: javascript, html

am in need of some help with this simple function so it would be great if you could help me
so this is the function

```
<script>
    function changeImage() {
        element = document.getElementById('myimage')
        if (element.src.match("bulbon")) {
            element.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
        } else {
            element.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
        }
    }
</script>

<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()"
src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light</p>
```

so if you click the image then it would turn on, if you click again it would turn off, like a switch.
what if i have 5 images that are the same with different Ids and if say the 1st one is on then the last one would turn off, if the 3rd one is on then the 2nd one would turn off and so on, how would i create that function with multiple Ids and also give it this if statement, i just need an idea of how this can be written.

thank you for reading, it would be great to see your replies

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid inline javascript and use a non-obstrusive approach instead.

Comment: Beware that you're currently falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare `element` in your function (`var element;`).

Comment: I forgot to remove a line from `changeImage` when I first posted my answer, it should be working code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your function to take an id as a parameter:

```
function changeImage(id) {
    var element=document.getElementById(id);
    if (element.src.match("bulbon")) {
        element.src="pic_bulboff.gif";
    }
    else {
        element.src="pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
```

After that, it will be easy to connect them to the switches and make a custom behaviour relations.

For example, to make the 5th one toggle when you click the first one, just change the onclick for the first one into something like: `onclick="changeImage('id_of_the_5th_image')"`

For a more complex logic, you might want to have a function that will keep track of all the lights and turn on/off some of them appropriately. For example, when you click *any* bulb, it will check whether the first one is lit, and if so, it will turn off the fifth one, etc.

UPDATE

Here is a simple example, it uses the most complex scenario I mentioned in the comments: http://jsfiddle.net/ChDES/

Comment: Although this answers the question, this is not the best approach when looking at the example provided by OP. The use of `this` seems to be the best one.

Comment: @Bartdude How would you make bulb1 turn off the bulb5 if you use `this`? The question is a bit more complex than just toggling clicked elements.

Comment: hi shomz, am trying to make this work, what would i change or add, am a little confused, how would the 1st turn off is the 5th one is on

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how exactly did you want your function to work (when you click bulb 1, does it turn on and turn bulb5 off, or just turns the bulb5 off, etc...), so  I didn't write that part. But if you explain it, I can probably help you more.

Comment: yah so if 5 is already on, if 1 is then clicked 5 would turn off and 1 would be on

Comment: I see, I suppose you can write an array of additional bulbs that are affected by each of them. So, for the bulb 1, the array would contain bulb 5, etc. However, if there are no cases when one bulb influences more than one other bulb, you don't even need an array. And, if there's a scenario in which the clicked bulb does not respond (example: you click #2, and only #4 lits), you might specify all the affected ones in the array. So, for bulb #1, the array would contain bulb 1 and bulb 5. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: okay yah, it does make alot of sense, am trying to get my head round it, but how would the code look, sorry if its no trouble can u give me an example of one turning off when the other one turns on

Comment: Sure, I'll write you something you can use.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it working. :) I see you're changing accepted answers - you can upvote all of those that were helpful, and accept the one that helped you the most. Of course, you can downvote useless ones too.

Comment: haha am not used to this website so i thought i can tick more the one

Comment: Yeah, that's what the up arrow is for :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<script>
    function changeImage(element) {
        if (element.src.match("bulbon")) {
            element.src="pic_bulboff.gif";
        } else {
            element.src="pic_bulbon.gif";
        }
    }
</script>

<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage(this)"
src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<img id="myimage1" onclick="changeImage(this)"
src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<img id="myimage2" onclick="changeImage(this)"
src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light</p>
```

---

**Edit**:
As suggested, this answer is insufficient for the question. If the OP wanted to toggle multiple bulbs the following could be done:

```
<script>
function changeImage(element, on) {
    if (typeof element === 'string') {
        element = document.getElementById(element);
    }
    if (on === false || bulbOn(element)) {
        element.src='pic_bulboff.gif';
    } else {
        element.src='pic_bulbon.gif';
    }
}

function bulbOn(element) {
    return element.src.indexOf('bulbon') > -1;
}
</script>

<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage(this); changeImage('myimage2', !bulbOn(this))"
src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<img id="myimage1" onclick="changeImage(this)"
src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<img id="myimage2" onclick="changeImage(this)"
src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">

<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light</p>
```

In this example, clicking the first image will always set the third image to the opposite state.

Comment: How does this do **anything** related to the bulb logic? Did you read the question at all?

Comment: yah thank you, I've changed it to this and I can add more than 1 bulb, works very well

Comment: @Shomz I suppose you corrected my wrong interpretation of the question incorrectly :P After reading it for the second time it did seem like I didn't provide a sufficient answer to be honest.

Comment: @BenBarkay Haha! Yeah, your example works as a simple element toggler, but OP needs a bit more than that.

Comment: hi, sorry i completely missed and I've tried it again, its very useful thank you, as soon as i have 15 credits i'll make sure i put a thump up to show this is useful, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

could this jsfiddle be of any help?

HTML:

```
<div id="bulb1" class="bulb on"></div>
<div id="bulb2" class="bulb off"></div>
<div id="bulb3" class="bulb on"></div>
<div id="bulb4" class="bulb off"></div>
<div id="bulb5" class="bulb on"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bulb {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #777;
}
.on {
    background-color: #ff0;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.bulb').click(function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
        if (this.id == 'bulb1') {
            $('#bulb5').toggleClass('on');
        } else if (this.id == 'bulb2') {
            $('#bulb3').toggleClass('on');
        } else if (this.id == 'bulb3') {
            $('#bulb4').toggleClass('on');
        } else if (this.id == 'bulb4') {
            $('#bulb1').toggleClass('on');
        } else if (this.id == 'bulb5') {
            $('#bulb2').toggleClass('on');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/laruiss/SZz5Y/1/

Anyway, it makes a funny game ;-) (Try to turn all the lights on or all the lights off).

Comment: haha that's really good thank you, that's actually the idea, nearly guessed it